# Copy Directory to Output Directory - Console Application .NET

Tags: c#, include, directory, copy

Is there a way to copy an entire directory to the output directory in a console application in C#.NET?

I know for files you can right click them, properties and mark copy to output directory. But I'm not going to do that for 20.000 files...

Thx, Lieven Cardoen aka Johlero

Comment: Why do you need the 20k files?  What are they?  I MUST KNOW, MAN!

Comment: If they are for reading only, consider hard-linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want all 20000 files in the output?

Besides manual copy-paste operation I see two options: one is you can have a post-build task to copy all the files and another is to have 20000 files zipped, zip file added as a content item to your project with "copy always" set and either console application unzip 'em, or a post-build step is calling unzip utility to do that.

Answer (score 3):

1. While in development, use application configuration to point to where these files CURRENTLY reside, instead of copying them. (copying that many objects on each build is a nightmare. Even if copying only new/updated files)
2. When preparing a release build, you might want to consider using a build script and MSBuild or NAnt to do this type of thing for you.
3. If you REALLY are convinced you are sure you still want to perform a copy on each build - use Post/pre-build script (in your project build configuration, point to a batch file which performs an xcopy.. some smart batch scripting can sometimes be very helpful).

Answer (score -3):

You could hit ctrl+A to highlight all of them, then hit ctrl+C to copy them, then go to the new directory and hit ctrl+V to paste them all to the new location...

Or you could open up the command window and use copy... but the first way is probably easier.